# NameError BeautifulSoup HTML parse

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I wrote the code that intended to search and remove div tags with specific class from multiple .html files in the local directory(recursively). Python 2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

root = '/path/to/directory/test'

for (dirpath, dirs, files) in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.html'):
            with open(fi) as f:
                content = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'sidebar'}):
        div.decompose()
```

It return an error:

```
  File "./parser.py", line 14, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser') NameError: name 'content' is not defined
```

I'm fairly new to python: how to fix it? At the end, I want to add a nice formatting of HTML code (in-place), making it readable and pretty, with the proper indentation. How to add this function?

Comment: The for loop never saw a filename that ends in `.html`, therefore `content` was never assigned.

Comment: the three last lines should be in the if block

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correction, keep in mind that the variable content was declarated in the 'if'block and since when you using the BeautifulSoup outside of it, the variable wasn't "visible"/defined.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

root = '/path/to/directory/test'

for (dirpath, dirs, files) in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.html'):
            with open(name) as f: #name instead of fi
                content = f.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
                for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'sidebar'}):
                    div.decompose()
```

Comment: another error: `File "./parser.py", line 10, in <module>
    with open(fi) as f:
NameError: name 'fi' is not defined`

Comment: because "fi" is not defined in your entire code as you can see in your code,probably missed typed with name.thats what you meant most likely `with open(name) as f:`

Comment: how is your code different from mine? can't see the difference.

Comment: The difference is `open(name)` instead of `open(fi)`.  As a typo, this should not have been entered as an answer, and the question should have been marked for closure.